Find all the positive integer n and prime number p such that $n^3-p^5=p^6+3n-2$.
I get really stuck on this question. My initial thought was that such equation generally does not have solutions expressible in radicals, since it has two variables and its degree is greater than 5 (based on principle from abstract algebra). However, considering this is a middle school-level problem, I suspect there might be other approaches or simplifications that I'm missing.
Could someone confirm whether my understanding of the question (not solvable by radicals) is correct? Additionally, I would appreciate any insights or alternative methods suitable for solving this problem.

Move all terms with $n$ on one side and terms with $p$ on the other side. Then try to simplify both sides...

$$n^3-3n+2=(n-1)^2(n+2)$$

From the (very helpful) comments, we can state that $n^3-3n+2=p^5(p+1)$. Note that $p$ and $(p+1)$ are coprime and $p^5>p+1$. Also note that $p^6+p^5 \ge 96 \Rightarrow n\ge 5$
Further note that $\gcd{(n-1),(n+2)}=1,3$. Thus the two terms $(n-1)^2$ and $(n+2)$ are either coprime or share a factor of $3$. Also, $n\ge 5 \Rightarrow (n-1)^2>(n+2)$
Edited in response to comment: It they are coprime, then either $p^5\mid (n-1)^2$ or $p^5\mid (n+2)$. But a perfect square cannot have exactly $5$ factors of $p$, and $n+2=kp^5$ is impossible because $n-1\approx kp^5$ leads to $k^2p^{10}\cdot kp^5\approx p^6+p^5$, so the two terms $(n-1)^2$ and $(n+2)$ must share a factor of $3$.
This requires either $p=3$ or $(p+1)=3$. $p=2$ affords no solution, but $p=3$ affords the solution $n=10$, as was obtained in another answer.

The "then it can only be the case" isn't clear without justification. Presumably $p^4$ should be $p^5$, but it's more than that: $ab=cd$ with $(a,b)=(c,d)=1$ doesn't imply ${a,b}={c,d}$.

Good point but you could replace $\approx$ with clear inequalities.

As suggested by the comments.
Move the terms at both sides and we have,
$n^3 - 3n +2 = p^5+p^6$
$(n-1)^2(n+2)=p^5(1+p)$
case 1:
$n-1 = p^2, n+2 = p(1+p)$ we get $p = 3$ and $n = 10$.
case 2:
$n-1 = p, n+2 = p^3(1+p)$, no solution for this case.
In summary, we have $p = 3$ and $n = 10$ as the solution.

Why only two cases?

The other answer is more complete, to be honest.
